# Regex: How to not match the last character of a word?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex that does not match a word (a-z only) if the word has a `:` on the end but otherwise matches it. However, **this word is in the middle of a larger regex** and so I (don't think) you can use a negative lookbehind and the `$` metacharacter.

I tried this negative lookahead instead:

```
([a-z]+)(?!:)
```

but this test case

```
example:
```

just matches to

```
exampl
```

instead of failing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a negative lookahead, you could put it at the beginning:

```
(?![a-z]*:)[a-z]+
```

i.e: "match at least one a-z char, except if the following chars are 0 to n 'a-z' followed by a ':'"

That would support a larger regex:

```
 X(?![a-z]*:)[a-z]+Y
```

would match in the following string:

```
 Xeee Xrrr:Y XzzzY XfffZ
```

only 'XzzzY'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[a-z]\s
```

Comment: And what about a word that is followed by punctuation other than ":"?

Comment: Sorry my fault! I forgoted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-z]+\b)(?!:)
```

asserts a word boundary at the end of the match and thus will fail "exampl"

Answer (score 0):

[a-z]+(?![:a-z])